# Ionic 3 / angular ngForm not sending data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm building a simple crud app with ionic 3, but I can't insert new data into the database, because the php server is getting an empty post array.

My ionic / angular code:

Insert.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="envioDato(f)">

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Nombre</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="name" ngModel #name = "ngModel"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> 
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Precio</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="price" ngModel #price = "ngModel"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> 
    <ion-item>
      <button ion-button full block color = "danger"> Enviar </button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  </form>
```

Insert.ts, this is the method specified in the form

```
envioDato(req){

    this.service.dataRegister(req.value).subscribe(

        data=> {
            this.showAlert(data.mensaje);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
            console.log(data);
        },
        err=>console.log(err)

    )

  }
```

And this is the method in the serviceProvider that sends the data to the server:

```
dataRegister(params){
    return this.http.post(this.api+'insert.php', params, {
        headers: {"content-Type" : "applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    }).map((res:Response) => {return res;});
  }
```

I can get responses from the server, but I can't send the data of the form to the server, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `template-driven` approach there's no need to assign your `inputs` to local variables. Simply add the `ng-model` directive to them. In addition, I think you would need to add `type="submit"` to your form.

Like this:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="envioDato(f)">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Nombre</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" name="name" ngModel></ion-input>
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Precio</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" name="price" ngModel></ion-input>
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item>
            <button ion-button full block color = "danger" type="submit"> Enviar </button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

I also recommend you to create the `httpOptions` the angular way:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'content-Type' : 'applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};
```

and then pass it like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.api+'insert.php', params, httpOptions).map((res:Response) => {return res;});
```